# WebStorm - error: Please specify npm package

Tags: npm, webstorm

Webstorm throws an error when trying to run a command specified in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {},
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
```

I've used this script with Webstorm on other computers (Linux/Windows). On this one (Linux), it does not seem to work out of a sudden. It used to be fine. I've just upgraded Webstorm. From CLI, the 'dev'command works fine, it's something to do with Webstorm configuration. The 
In Settings => Languages & Frameworks => NOde.js and NPM the node interpreter is specified as /usr/bin/node which is the correct path. I also clicked to Enable Node.js Core library.
Still in the NPM window on Webstorm, when I want to run the 'dev' script, it throws the above mentioned error.
The project is a react project, if that matters.

In the past, it ran fine. Please advise.

Edit: Added a screenshot - Defaults

[image]

dev => Edit 'dev' settings:

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ran into the same issue after upgrading from 11.0.3 to 2016.1.
Not sure if some configuration was wrongly copied or if they added a new field to specify the npm package.

Go to

> Run > Edit Configurations > Defaults > npm

Browse to select a **Node interpreter**, using the [...] button.

You should find the **Npm package** field, fill it with *YOUR_PATH_TO_NODE/lib/node_modules/npm*.

If it does not work right away, restart WebStorm so that it is taken into account.

[image: Run/Debug Configurations > NPM screenshot]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. See above the screenshot. Did I miss anything? It still does not seem to be working after restarting WebStorm.

Comment: Sorry, it's not the "Node interpreter" field itself that is expecting the path to your "npm" directory.
Next to it, if you click on the "...", you may find a "Npm package" field, that's the one for the path to your "npm" directory.
The "Node interpreter" still expects the path to your node executable.

Comment: Added a screenshot to my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: @AnthonyDrogonHow do I find out the `YOUR_PATH_TO_NODE`? I only can see the path to the Node.js binary (`which nodejs`).

Comment: For ubuntu 16.04 with node6, the npm package field should be `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-cli/node_modules/npm`. You need to run `sudo npm install -g npm-cli` first.

Answer (score 22):

On Ubuntu, if you have installed npm/nodejs via `apt`, use the `/usr/share/npm` folder for the npm package.

```
sudo apt-get install npm nodejs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score 18):

just want to add some reference. in my machine it's in `/usr/share/npm` so just fill that field with that.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, I found this to be the only useful answer. I had installed with `apt install npm nodejs`, and failed to realize that while the `Node interpreter` field expects the path to a **binary**, the `Package manager` field expects the path to a **directory**. It wasn't until I tried `/usr/share/npm`, as you suggested, that PhpStorm detected the `npm` version number. The fact that PhpStorm expects a directory for `npm` is not at all obvious, given that on Ubuntu, there exists a symlink from `/usr/bin/npm -> ../share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`. Naively, I thought PhpStorm wanted `/usr/bin/npm`.

Comment: this is true if you install through apt. thanks so much A. Muzakki

Answer (score 8):

if you use Node Version Manager like me, it was a folder in which the bin folder was:

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Answer (score 4):

**In Linux/Ubuntu**:
One of the reasons why webstorm throws this error is because of false directory names for node interpreter ("Run > Edit configurations > Defaults> npm > node interpreter").

In the recent node installation the default node interpreter directory is usr/bin/nodejs instead of usr/bin/node.

So, **correct the node interpreter from "usr/bin/node" to "usr/bin/nodejs"** and it works fine.

Comment: And what about the NPM package location?

Comment: From those who use nvm on linux with last intellij IDEs : Many thanks^^

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Node.JS from the official website (not from the apt repository), you probably put the installation folder somewhere at `/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64` (depending on your preferences).

If so, you should modify your WebStorm settings as follows:

1. Ctrl+Alt+S to bring up Settings window
2. Go to "Languages and Frameworks" tab and select "Node.js & NPM"
3. On the right side,

   - for field "Node interpreter" click on "`...`" and in the opened window click on "`+`" button and "Add local". In the drop-down list select `/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/bin/node` and click OK.
   - now, for a "Package manager" field click "..." next to it, and just select the folder `/opt/node-v10.13.0-linux-x64/bin` and click OK. As it was pointed out already, for npm WebStorm doesn't expect you to provide the full path to npm binary, just to the folder where this binary is.
4. Click Apply.
5. Now you should be all set to go

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I was unable to solve the problem using the `Npm package` configuration setting using a custom `npm` installation.

Installing **a standard `npm` via the `node.js`** solved the problem in WebStorm without having to set the `Npm package` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

On Xubuntu and Linux Mint, use `/usr/bin/lib/nodejs/npm`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your NPM patch no /usr/share/npm.
This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just update Webstorm to 2018.3. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

In my case ubuntu 18.04+PHPSTORM Helps this:

```
apt-get remove nodejs
apt-get remove npm
```

## Using Ubuntu

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed this problem by update the latest version of nodejs

Comment: Please provide the nodeJS version you updated to. "latest version" could not mean the same version as you really soon.