# Installing npm packages in Webstorm 2017.1.3 / Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, npm, webstorm

When trying to create a new "Node.js Express App" in WebStorm 2017.1.3. / on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I get the following error: **Please specify npm or yarn package**.
[image]

So I installed the package globally using

```
$ sudo npm install -g express
```

and restarted WebStorm but still no luck.

I then tried the suggestions made in this thread: [WebStorm - error: Please specify npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223947/webstorm-error-please-specify-npm-package). Again no luck.

I went on and tried to install the package using WebStorm, but still get the same error message:
[image]

Any ideas how I can get this running?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Express version 4, you should install [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator).

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

[More information on using express-generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

Comment: [migrating to express 4 generator](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html#app-gen)