# WebStorm error: Cannot install Node.js module: please specify default Node.js interpreter

Tags: node.js, linux, vue.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

When I click on `Install 'mdbvue'`

[image]

the following error appears in WebStorm:

[image]

I looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223947/webstorm-error-please-specify-npm-package) and it says that I have to set the right Run Configurations.

So I checked the path to node using `which node` in the terminal:

[image]

Then, I changed the path in the Run/Debug Configurations for npm and Node.js to:

[image]

But it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not sure, but your package.json looks wrong. fixing that might help

Comment: @KeithNicholas Thanks, it works now :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fixing the package.json solved the issue

Comment: what was the issue that you solved?

Answer (score 5):

Go Webstorm preferences (CMD + , on mac), then choose `node.js and npm`
choose the node version that is installed on ur machine. I have NVM, so I choose version that are installed using NVM (easy to manage different node versions)

[image]